# where is located wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to replace "Choose an option” with corresponding attribute/variation name so modify the wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options so where is located in wordpress folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` declaration of `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options` is located in `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`.

You can also have access to the arguments with this filter `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args )`